# returning a report in Odoo blocks workflow

Tags: report, workflow, odoo

I am working on customizing the Sale Order in Odoo v8 and I want the Sales Order to be automatically printed when I click "Confirm Order". On my first try I did this:

```
  def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    res = super(sale_order, self).action_button_confirm(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    data = self.read(cr, uid, ids)[0]       
    datas = {
        'ids': ids,
        'model': 'sale.order',
        'form': data
    }
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'er_sale.report_er_invoice_header',          
        'report_type': 'qweb-html',
        'datas': datas
    }
```

The report appears as a pop-up but the original page doesn't refresh, so the "Confirm Order" still remains.

Is there a way to refresh the original page while still returning a report action?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code..

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    res = super(sale_order, self).action_button_confirm(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    self.print_quotation(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
return res
```

Hope this help...